# Angular: Check if an injected service is the "global" instance of that service

Tags: angular, typescript

Can a component check if the service it injected is the "global" instance of that service, or otherwise require a non-singleton instance?

Let's say I have a complex component called `<huge-table></huge-table>`. This component uses several services, all of which should each have their own local instance. I want this component to **require** it's own instance of these services, therefore forcing the parent component which uses `<huge-table>` to have them as providers.

Note:

Setting these services as providers inside the `<huge-table>` component itself is not possible in my case, since there are sibling components which also need the same local instance.

e.g.:

```
<huge-table></huge-table>
<sibling-component></sibling-component>
```

...and both need the same local service instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long I follow. You will need include these services in the parent providers array. Remember to put them in constructors. And remove `providedIn: 'root'` from your services. It should be just `@Injectable()`